# How to add the logs to a crontab with time stamp

Tags: bash, scripts, cron, logs

In crontab, I scheduled a daily backup script. Now when the cron executes the script the status are logged to a log file as shown below.

```
0 0 * * * /home/backup.sh > /home/groupz/db-backup/fbackup.log 2>&1
```

Now, when the cron executes a script the contents of the log get renewed everytime. So, I want the contents to be added to the same file with time stamp of the executed time and below the contents of each time along with the existing contents. How can I do this.

Comment: Don't forget to escape the "%" character in your crontab! `+%d-%m-%y/%H:%M:%S` Would become : `+\%d-\%m-\%y/\%H:\%M:\%S`

Answer (score 9):

why not just

`0 * * * * (/bin/date && /home/backup.sh) >> /var/log/backup.log 2>&1`

Answer (score 5):

**How to get timestamp in a file**

To add a time stamp in a file you can use `date` see `man date` for more
details. For example if you use in terminal you will have output like,

```
$ date +%d-%m-%y/%H:%M:%S
19-12-13/09:14:42
```

The output is in the format `dd-mm-yy/hour:min:sec`

If you wish to put the time stamp in a file, use

```
date +%d-%m-%y/%H:%M:%S > filename
```

**Redirection**

If you use `date +%d-%m-%y/%H:%M:%S > filename` then the date will be stored into the file but it it will be overwritten every time you use the command. To append it in an existing file use,

```
date +%d-%m-%y/%H:%M:%S >> filename
```

It will add the last execution output at the end of your existing file.

**What you do in your case**

You can add the following line at the end of your `/home/backup.sh`,

```
date +%d-%m-%y/%H:%M:%S
```

And use the following in crontab,

```
0 0 * * * /home/backup.sh >> /home/groupz/db-backup/fbackup.log 2>&1
```

I think the above modification should do what you want.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

(On Debian Jessie) Use the `ts` command which is part of the `moreutils` package. E.g.:

```
0 0 * * * /home/backup.sh | ts '[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]' > /home/groupz/db-backup/fbackup.log 2>&1
```

This will prepend the timestamp to every line of the output and save it into your log.

Comment: Didn't work for me, I'm using Ubuntu 16.04. I installed `moreutils`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are running a shell script, why not add a line like,

```
some ./script    
echo `date -u `
some ./other/script
```

in your script ie /home/backup.sh

Then

```
0 0 * * * /home/backup.sh >> /home/groupz/db-backup/fbackup.log 2>&1
```

will append a line before/after fbackup.log like 
Thu Jun 14 11:10:22 UTC 2018

Comment: Isn't `echo \`date -u\`` the same as `data -u`?

Comment: The echo adds a line break AIUI.

Answer (score -2):

You can append something to a file using two of these things '>'.

```
$ echo "test" >> test.txt
$ echo "test" >> test.txt

$ cat test.txt
test
test
```

Comment: What about timestamp